# AuraPHP DI dynamic class or decision based injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection, auraphp

I'm new to modern method of dependency injection and I'm trying to figure out how to have a method pick which class to use based on a condition. I bet I've got my design structure off but I'm also not seeing how to do this in Aura DI through the config.

This is my Aura Config

```
<?php
namespace Aura\Cli_Project\_Config;

use Aura\Di\Config;
use Aura\Di\Container;

class Common extends Config {
    public function define(Container $di) {
        // utilities
        $di->set(
            'App\Inventory\Utilities\EmailParser',
            $di->newInstance('App\Inventory\Utilities\PlancakeParser')
        );

        // commands
        $di->params['App\Inventory\Command\IncomingOrder'] = array(
            'stdio' => $di->lazyGet('aura/cli-kernel:stdio'),
            'parser' => $di->get('App\Inventory\Utilities\EmailParser')
        );
    }
    // ...
}
```

And this is the class in question that needs to use different classes depending on the "source" it finds.

```
<?php

namespace App\Inventory\Command;

use Aura\Cli\Stdio;
use App\Inventory\Utilities\EmailParser;
use App\Inventory\Sources\Etsy;
use App\Inventory\Sources\Amazon;
use App\Inventory\Sources\Ebay;

class IncomingOrder {

    public function __construct(
        Stdio $stdio,
        EmailParser $parser) {
        $this->stdio = $stdio;
        $this->parser = $parser;
    }

    public function process() {
        // other code to parse message
        // source is set by determining where it came from
        $source = 'Etsy';

        switch($source) {
            case 'Etsy' :
                // This bit seems really wrong
                $sourceParser = new Etsy\OrderParser();
                break;
            case 'Amazon' :
                $sourceParser = new Amazon\OrderParser();
                break;
            case 'Ebay' :
                $sourceParser = new Ebay\OrderParser();
                break;
            default :
                $sourceParser = null;
        }

        // Do source specific processing
    }
}
```

Is it that I need to split my processing at the point right after the source is determined so a new class can be initialized with that source as a parameter?

The only way I can see to do this in the config is to do a lazy anonymous function to return the proper source class but this also feels against modern design principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something I would like to clarify is you don't need to use `set` method like many of the di containers out here. You can modify the code to

```
<?php
namespace Aura\Cli_Project\_Config;

use Aura\Di\Config;
use Aura\Di\Container;

class Common extends Config 
{
    public function define(Container $di) 
    {
        // commands
        $di->params['App\Inventory\Command\IncomingOrder'] = array(
            'stdio' => $di->lazyGet('aura/cli-kernel:stdio'),
            'parser' => $di->lazyNew('App\Inventory\Utilities\EmailParser')
        );
    }
    // ...
}
```

You can make use of `set` when you want to pass the same object to many other objects. Don't use `newInstance` for it will create the object on calling the same. You probably may need to make use of `lazyNew` or `lazyGet` functionalities.

Regarding your question about dynamic decision making. Here is my thoughts, I did have came across this question some time before. But didn't see what I did so iirc what I did was injected a factory to  `IncomingOrder` class which can create object. The good thing about it is if your source parse needs some sort of dependency you can make use of di inside the factory.

Eg :

```
<?php
namespace Something;

use Aura\Di\Container;

class SourceFactory
{
    public function __construct(Container $di) 
    {   
        $this->di = $di;
    }

    public function newInstance($source)
    {
        if ($di->has($source)) {
            return $di->get($source);
        }
        // or alternatively create with new as done in switch
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Thank you

Comment: So in my config I put definitions for the various source parsers. If I'm understanding correctly then, the `SourceFactory` is injected into the `IncomingOrder` then after the source is known I call `$sourceParser = $this->sourceFactory->newInstance($source)`. I will try this. Thank you very much.